Android app not in fullscreen even though the flags are set to be fullscreened
I'm still new to .NET MAUI, and I'm trying to make a simple FTP client app for my phone. However, I'm unable to set it to full screen.
I've set the flags, but whenever I test it on my local device, it refuses to full screen. Here's a screenshot:

Here's my MainActivity.cs the Android platform:
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using AndroidX.Core.View;

namespace FTPBuddy
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Window?.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen | WindowManagerFlags.LayoutInScreen);
            Window?.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.ForceNotFullscreen);

            var controller = Window?.InsetsController;
            controller?.Hide(WindowInsets.Type.SystemBars());
        }
    }
}

If somebody could help solve this issue, that would be great, thanks!

You can try to use the following code to make your app full screen:
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits, WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
            Window.Attributes.LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode = LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode.ShortEdges;
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiFlags =
                (SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
                 SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen | SystemUiFlags.Immersive);

        }
    }


This got it to work, thank you!
